# sails.js preload action in controller

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I need a help in sails.js framework.i am developing the website in nodejs and sails.js framework.
is there any way to call preload action in each controller.(for ex: the controller calling time load this action).each controller having different pre load action.

Please any one suggest to me.how can i create this way or any other way.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Can you be a little more clear as to what a "preload action" in a controller is, and what it would do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a service:

/service/mypre.js:

```
exports.first = function(req,res,cb) {
     // here add you code

     cb();
}
```

in Controller:

```
module.exports = {
    index: function(req,res) {
       sails.mypre.first(req,res, function(){

          // Do other things...
       });

    }
}
```

And you may add a callback to make sure, your mypre() is done completely.